# How to print consecutive numbers without spaces until reaching the user's input in python

Tags: python, loops, printing

I've been trying to solve this [Test](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-print/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_r=next-challenge&h_r=next-challenge&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_v=zen&h_v=zen&h_v=zen&isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen), but I can't print the numbers in one line using  ***While loop***, any ideas?

this is my code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
num = 1
while num <= n:
    print(num )
    num = num +1
```

Comment: Instead of linking externally, you should write everything here. Also, include what you've tried and how it hasn't worked. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You will need to set the "end" keyword argument to an empty string like this: `print('What you're printing here', end='')`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! As this is not a code-writing or tutorial service, we ask that questions include a [mcve] in the body of the question describing the problem, and showing _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research so that we can understand how to offer specific help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As drake14w said, you have to use the end keyword argument to avoid automatic line break.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i, end='')
    print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really simple, and the people in the comment also pointed out that you should make your question more detailed, and without linking external resources which aren't really needed, however this is the solved problem.

```py
from __future__ import print_function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(raw_input())
    for x in range(n):
        print(x + 1, end='')
```

Comment: `raw_input()`? Are you on Python 2? You may want to explicitly point that out in your answer

Comment: that's what the site he linked uses.

Comment: Uh, ok, I didn't check